# Can't type semicolon with Java Robot class

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am trying to type a semicolon using the Java `Robot` class but it is not functioning properly. It simply will not type anything and it causes me to highlight everything I click after the program ends. Does someone know why this is not working?

Here is my code:

```
  public class tEST {

    public static void main (String []args) throws AWTException {

        Robot robot=new Robot();
        robot.delay(2000);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);

        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not look for `VK_SEMICOLON` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the semicolon, look instead for:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
```

rather than the combination of keys (different keyboards have different layouts).

Documentation link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_SEMICOLON

Answer (score 0):

The correct KeyEvent constant for semicolon is VK_SEMICOLON

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
```